# Visual Code and OpenCV : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, include

as python user who uses "pip install ..." i am a little bit overwhelemed by the complexity to do the same -library implementation- in c++.

I try to include OpenCV into my C++ code (for many hours now) but it doesn't work anyhow.
error: opencv2\opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

OpenCV is included in system paths
and also in Visual Code configurations.

env: Visual Studio Code
OS: Win
lib: opencv-4.5.3-vc14_vc15
compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [good example](https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-opencv-with-visual-studio/) to install opencv with VS, try it step by step.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply but i worked through all these google results and nothing worked for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just tried by myself according to the example above, it works, so please check carefully for your configuration one by one. "Step 5: Include OpenCV in Visual Studio" is easy to make mistake, **C:\opencv\build\include**, **C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib**, **opencv_world341d.lib**, you should keep consistent on v14 or v15, then for VS, pay attention that you should configure above information under **debug x64**.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for your help. As u said: I am using Visual Studio Code so things are similar but not the same at all. Anyway it should be simple: installing opencv and VS Code, install c++ tool on VS Code, tell this tool where opencv is and lets go: theoretically. But here is still nothing working at all. It is horrible and i do not know how to work it out.

Comment: i just want to use opencv so i would be also okay with cmd execution of my code snippet.

Comment: As I can't see your details step by step, I really can't help. But I question you that why you must use C++ openCV, it seems you are a python user, why not use python openCV directly?